# How to obtain vertex position and rotation data from a mesh made from geometry nodes?

Tags: python, mesh, geometry-nodes, coordinates

I'm attempting to obtain location and rotation data on each vertex in a curve mesh that I draw on top of a shape, but **I cannot find a way to export this information**. For my project, I need the  vertices to be tangent to the curve and normal to the surface of the shape, separated at an equal distance. I'm using this data on my home-made CNC from parts that I modeled in Blender.

To start I select my shape, in this example I'm using a *Mesh Sphere*. Next, I create a *Curve Bezier*, go to edit mode, select all vertices and delete them, then select the *Draw Tool* and select *Surface - Method of projecting depth*, and draw my curve on the shape. I then apply a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and set the *Target* to *Sphere*.

Then I apply the following geometry nodes:[image: Geometry Nodes]

I've verified this gives me approximately the correct information, but I haven't found any way to extract the data that I generated. I expect there is some method of using python scripting, but I haven't had any success in my searches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what do you mean by export? into a spreadsheet or as an attribute on the mesh? o. the sphere or on the curve? it's not so clear what you mean.